# Recording success/failures from a list of event using a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have an list of events `['one', 'two', 'three']`. These events can either pass or fail. I want to build a decision tree to record the possible outcomes -- that is:

```
                    <root>
                      /\
      <one_pass>              <one_fail>
          /\                      /\
<two_pass>  <two_fail>  <two_pass>  <two_fail>
...
```

From [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825715/create-binary-tree-from-list-of-lists-in-python) [great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015508/construct-a-tree-from-a-list-with-levels?rq=1) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677906/tree-traversal-recursion), I can see that recursion is the way to go with this, seemingly in conjunction with a binary tree. What I'm struggling with is the loop to build out the pass/fails at each level... Is it a `for` loop or do I use recursion?

My starting point for the code is from the [answer I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677906/tree-traversal-recursion), copied in below for easy reference. (I will want to store values in each of the nodes at a later stage, then calculate the sum of these, hence I started here):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, children=None):
        if children is None:
            children = []
        self.data = data
        self.children = children

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    __repr__ = __str__

def get_all_paths(node, path=None):
    paths = []
    if path is None:
        path = []
    path.append(node)
    if node.children:
        for child in node.children:
            paths.extend(get_all_paths(child, path[:]))
    else:
            paths.append(path)
    return paths
```

I have manually built the following to start working out how to create the full structure, which is where I've got stuck.

```
tree = Node("start", [
        Node("one_pass", [
            Node("two_pass"), 
            Node("two_fail")
        ]),
        Node("one_fail", [
            Node("two_pass"),
            Node("two_fail")
        ])
    ])
```

From trying this out, I'm stuck at the `for` loop level.. which makes me think that I am not aware of the approach to use here. If the loop created two nodes on each pass -- basically creating both the left and right children nodes in one iteration -- how do I link them to the previous node? Do I need a method that does something like the following pseudocode?

```
for event in events:
    insert_node(my_tree, event, "pass")
    insert_node(my_tree, event, "fail")
```

NB I have 15 levels of the tree if that impacts anything.

Comment: So your goal is to create tree based on list automatically?

Comment: @ingvar Yes, that's correct

Comment: @ingvar okay, do both then.. show off!! :D Two questions: (1) In your thoughts, is there any preference between either implementation? (2) Am I correct in thinking that here that to link the levels you first create the children nodes and then link to the parent nodes?

Comment: @ingvar Does the implementation make any difference if there is a left and right node in the class definition, as opposed to a children array? I saw this in a number of solutions.

Comment: 1) For tree wth depth ~15 both implementation will work enough fast. Personally I prefer recursive implementation, it's less difficult to read 2) Yeah, I create child nodes and add them to parent later. Techically you can generate child nodes in node constructor.

Comment: 3) There is no difference. Arrays are used for high/unknown number of child nodes, while left/right are used for binary trees only. I used class `Node` that you provided but in fact it's even better to use left/right naming here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190040/discussion-between-ingvar-and-blue-otter-hat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate your tree using following code (non-recursive):

```
def generate_nodes(parent, data):  # adds data_pass and data_fail child nodes to parent
    passed = Node(data + '_pass')
    failed = Node(data + '_fail')
    parent.children.append(passed)
    parent.children.append(failed)

    return [passed, failed]  # returns new nodes


events = ['one', 'two', 'three']
root = Node('root')  # root of our tree
current_level_events = [root]  # nodes of currently processed level

for data in events:  # go through all events
    tmp = []
    for event in current_level_events:
        tmp += generate_nodes(event, data)  # generate events 
    current_level_events = tmp
```

Recursive implementation:

```
events = ['one', 'two', 'three']

def generate_nodes(parent, index):
    if index >= len(events):  # we finished tree generation, no more events found
        return
    data = events[index]
    passed = Node(data + '_pass')
    failed = Node(data + '_fail')
    parent.children.append(passed)
    parent.children.append(failed)
    # generate children for passed and failed nodes
    generate_nodes(passed, index + 1)
    generate_nodes(failed, index + 1)


events = ['one', 'two', 'three']
root = Node('root')  # root of our tree

generate_nodes(root, 0)  # starts tree generation
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons binary structures are so useful is that they are very easy to store in memory and index with just some math tricks.

If all your conditions are known ahead of time, it is very easy to consider your list of `['pass', 'fail', 'pass', 'fail' etc..]` as a binary number (`[1, 0, 1, 0]: 10`) with which to use as an index into a list pre-allocated to the length of the total possible outcomes (2<sup>N</sup> where N is the number of conditions).

If you need to store values at each stage of decision making (ie: store a value for `['pass','fail']` as well as `['pass', 'fail', 'fail']`) This is a little more involved, but still not that difficult. We know that any given number of conditions yields 2<sup>N</sup> possible outcomes, so we can also know how many outcomes are given with N-1 conditions, and N-2 etc. In total there are 2<sup>N</sup>-1 conditions of all shorter condition lists before the the 2<sup>N</sup> conditions that relate to N conditions. By adding our binary number as we found it earlier to 2<sup>N</sup>-1, we can get a unique index for each possible list of conditions.

If you have long lists of conditions, it is pretty easy to see that the list of possible outcomes grows exponentially. If you never plan on visiting all possible outcomes, it may be beneficial to use a dictionary with numeric keys rather than a list to store all possible outcomes.

given your example:

```
                        <root> (0)
                    /               \
          <one_pass> (1)           <one_fail> (2)
             /     \                     /     \
    <two_pass>(3) <two_fail>(4) <two_pass>(5) <two_fail>(6)
      /  \          /  \           /   \           /    \
   (7)  (8)      (9)    (10)     (11)   (12)    (13)    (14)
 /  \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \
15, 16, 17, 18| 19, 20, 21, 22| 23, 24, 25, 26| 27, 28, 29, 30
```

from here it is easy to come up with some functions to convert a list of `['pass', 'fail', 'pass', 'fail']` into an index:

```
def list_to_number(L):
    acc = 0
    for item in L:
        acc *= 2 #shift number left as we shift in values from the right
        if item == 'fail': #assumes pass == 0 fail == 1
            acc += 1
    return acc


def idx(L): 
    return 2**len(L) - 1 + list_to_number(L)
```

Full example:

```
#  Assume we will never have more than 4 events:
#  With 4 events we have 2**4 outcomes.
#  In total there are 2**5-1 possible outcomes including intermediate steps.
#  We will preallocate a list filled with `None` to length 2**5-1 so we have 
#    enough space for all possible outcomes.
tree_data = [None]*(2**5-1)

#insert value 42 given [event_1_pass, event_2_pass, event_3_fail]
tree_data[idx(['pass', 'pass', 'fail'])] = 42

#insert value 56 given [event_1_pass, event_2_pass, event_3_pass, event_4_pass]
tree_data[idx(['pass', 'pass', 'pass', 'pass'])] = 56

#retrieve value given [event_1_pass, event_2_pass, event_3_fail]
print(tree_data[idx(['pass', 'pass', 'fail'])])
# prints: 42

#retrieve value given [event_1_fail, event_2_pass, event_3_fail]
print(tree_data[idx(['fail', 'pass', 'fail'])])
# prints: None because we never stored anything there.
```

Comment: Apologies, I do not follow your answer: Are you able to expand? My situation is closer to the third paragraph, where I will store a number at each node. How does the binary number work here?

Comment: @BlueOtterHat do the two edits I just made clear anything up?

Comment: apologies again, the additional edit didn't help: I don't think that your explanation is poor, we're just up against the limits of my knowledge. When I run list_to_number([0,1,2]) I get 0, and when I run idx([0,1,2]) I get 7. Q: What area of computer science should I go read to educate myself on, as I'm lacking a foundation level of understanding here?

Comment: @BlueOtterHat no worries, I think the only thing you're getting hung up on is converting your list to a number. The list you pass in must consist of the **results** of the events: `['fail', 'pass', 'fail', 'pass']` this then gives you the index to a tree that may or may not yet exist. It does not create a tree for you.

Comment: You then can use a list to store the values at each given index (make sure it's long enough first) or you can use a dictionary if you either don't know how long it will need to be, or if you don't plan on visiting most of the possible outcomes.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. Are there any topics you suggest I go read up on to help learn more in this area you have described?